# Does running imagemagick multiple times degrade image quality?

Tags: imagemagick

I run a website and we have a number of folks working on page development.  Despite multiple training sessions, many of them upload unoptimized images to the site.  We want to run a batch compression using imagemagick that catches those images and resizes them down.  We're looking at using imagemagick, as that's what's installed on our server.  However, we're wondering if we can run that batch multiple times on the same images or whether that will cause degradation every time and eventually the images will suffer from it.  Is there an easy way to prevent that from happening?

Comment: What is the format of your images?  If they are PNG, no.  If they are JPEG, they might degrade over the first pass or two but then settle down.

Comment: They're mostly JPEGs.  I'm looking to compress them at the 85% level.

Comment: Why don't you check the image's meta data and see what the quality is first. If higher than 85%, then you could recompress them, if you want. But that would not be as good as starting with a non-compressed format and compressing to 85% and saving as jpg. I suggest you do some tests to see if the quality is reduced enough that you notice. I suggest you also check to see what the colorspace is and convert to sRGB using profiles. Be sure that any sRGB image has an sRGB profile. That way, the images should display consistently across different viewers.

Comment: There is also a jpeg:extent function that you could use to specify a file size rather than a quality level. See http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/formats/#jpg_write

Comment: @kenja: You can try jpeg-archive(try small-fry with high quality) to achieve good compression. This on average provided 56% reduction in size on our test dataset of 10000 files. https://github.com/danielgtaylor/jpeg-archive

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question is about generation loss, with repeated compression using the same "quality".  The answer depends upon whether chroma subsampling is enabled.
Chroma sub-sampling is used in ImageMagick by default for quality values less than 90.

Therefore, for quality values of 90 or greater (or if the -sampling-factor option is used to prevent subsampling), there should be little generation loss after the first pass or two.

I suggest that OP use quality=90 for the project.

Here is an article entitled [Why JPEG is like a photocopier](http://cloudinary.com/blog/why_jpeg_is_like_a_photocopier) that explains generation loss and the effect of chroma sub-sampling.

EDIT: I ran some experiments, and they did not exactly bear out my assertions.
Some images (mostly photos) converged very quickly, in 2 or 3 iterations, while others (drawings) took as many as 30 iterations in the worst case.  Sub-sampling took a little longer to converge, and quality 90 took a little longer than quality 85.  Here are a variety of 64x64-pixel images, all enlarged 4 times to make the individual pixels visible: [image: results]

Comment: Thanks.  That's very helpful.  What if an image has been optimized at a lower value previously, say a quality level of 50, and then you run the utility with a quality level of 90, what happens?  It can't really add information to the image, so does it just leave it as is?

Comment: The image of the lady scanned from an old photograph is at quality 50.  The filesize is slightly larger when converted to quality 85 or 90 but not much.